# Eclipse formatter for java ending braces

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I would like to know if it's possible to setup eclipse to format braces using banner style.  We're working with code that uses banner style formatting and would like to keep it consistent within the team for version control reasons.  Here's an example of banner style formatting for those who are not familiar:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        boolean condition = true;
        try {
            if (condition) {
                System.out.println ("condition is true");
                }
            else System.out.println ("not condition");
            }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle errors
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: Another name for this style is [Ratliff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Ratliff_style).

Answer (score -1):

Experiment with your Java->Code Style->Formatter preferences.  "Banner style" seems like a poor use of space given the Outline View and Quick Outline functionality.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "poor use of space".  The only problem seems to be with the closing braces not being able to indent.  This is the way all the code is in version control and we don't want it to deviate from the way it is now.  Using other formatters, such as astyle, support this banner style but I don't seem to see a way to set it up in eclipse.

Comment: The extra lines of comments, @cmevoli.

Comment: @nitind Ratliff is about horizontal indentation not about vertical spacing. So, the comment lines are the dev's personal taste.

Comment: Correct, the comment lines are not related to this formatting style.   They are just separators we use in some code blocks.    I can remove them from the initial question since they are leading to confusion.   Also, we are not looking for a solution in Eclipse anymore.  We have since moved to Netbeans.